# Cover a polygon with K rectangles minimizing the rectangles area

Tags: algorithm

Given a general polygon P (might contain holes) and a number of rectangles K, I want to find K rectangles {r1,r2,...,rk} such that the polygon is contained in the union of these rectangles. Also, I want to minimize the area of the union of the rectangles.

Note that the rectangles may overlap each other. Also, they're axis-aligned.

As an example, for K=1, the algorithm should report the minimum bounding box.

I've read some papers on the subject, namely "A linear-time approximation algorithm for minimum rectangular covering" and "Covering a polygonal region by rectangles".

The first article approaches the problem by dividing the polygon into simpler polygons, but it considers only rectangles that are within the polygon.
The second article assumes that the rectangles dimension are fixed and simply translates them around and tries to cover the polygon with the minimum number of rectangles.

I know that there is an article named "covering a polygon with few rectangles" that has what I believe to be exactly what I'm looking for, but I would have to pay in order to have access to it and I'd like to dig depeer before spending any money.

Since this is an np-complete or np-hard (not sure) problem, i'm not expecting fast exact algorithms, therefore approximations are also relevant.

Does anyone have knowledge of previous work on this particular problem? Any work that might relate is also welcome. Also, if you have ideas on how to address the problem it would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the rectangles axis-aligned or can they have any orientation?

Comment: axis-aligned. But solutions with rotated rectangles are also welcome.

Comment: Regarding the paid paper: I don't want to link to a potentially copyrighted paper, so have a look at this [math's answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/105183) :-)

Comment: eheh nice way of putting it. Well, I've had a look at it, but it does not really provide an explanation nor references to the algorithms they use. They simply say, we did this is O(N) for K<=3. Disapointing... Thanks a bunch